# Nginx proxy not redirecting when using url name?

Tags: docker, nginx

When I type in the IP address of the reverse proxy directly into my browser bar, it does perform the redirect.

When using a URL that is resolved via the `/etc/hosts` entry `203.0.113.2 git.example.com` the "Welcome to Ngnix page" is shown.  Any ideas?  This is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name git.example.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://203.0.113.1:3000;
    }
}
```

One interesting thing is that I can navigate to for example:

```
http://203.0.113.2/issues
```

If I then change `203.0.113.2` with `git.example.com` I get Nginxs "404 not found" page.

Comment: welcome nginx is shown on dault port 80 , so you need to make sure it hits the same port 3000 or 80  in both cases to troubeshoot further

Comment: http://203.0.113.2/issues
means that your backend port is also 80

Comment: The `issues` path is served by the proxy target, which runs on port 3000 on `203.0.0113.1`

Comment: how it is hit by proxy target? you are accesing the ip directly without going through proxy in that case

Comment: The nginx server is running on `203.0.113.2`.  The Gogs server is running on `203.0.113.1`.  So when we hit `203.0.113.2/issues` it redirects to `203.0.113.1:3000/issues` and I can see the issues page.